# How to print on JSP after forwarding on to it?

Tags: java, json, jsp, servlets

Here is the servlet part:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
session.getAttribute("XMLData");
String jsonArray = gson.toJson(xmlFromDB);
RequestDispatcher reqDis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
reqDis.forward(request, response);
response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);
```

JSP:

```
<body>
   <div align="center">
        <table id="list">
            <tr>
                <td />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</body>
```

js file :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#list").jqGrid({
    url : "GridServlet",
    datatype : "json",
    mtype : 'POST',
    ...
});
```

But when I'm forwarding to `index.jsp`, blank jq grid is displayed instead of json array that I'm printing.

Comment: Have you tried writing to the response before forwarding it?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your `servlet URL pattern` matches `URL` attribute in js file and js is included in `index.jsp`.

Remove this from your servlet:

```
RequestDispatcher reqDis = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
reqDis.forward(request, response);
```

Forwarding request takes control from the servlet and pass it to jsp page as you are forwarding request before writing response so no response from the servlet takes place. And one more thing you don't need to run servlet in this example as long as you have included `js file` in `index.jsp` than you only need to run `index.jsp` that's it, if you have set correct data format you will get your desired output.